# Calculo Recursivo en Java

Tags: java, recursión

Estoy aprendiendo programacion con java y  tengo este problema delante

Tengo que realizar el siguiente calculo recursivo

int q = le doy valor por teclado

x1 = 1

x2 = ((q/x1)+x1)/ 2

x3 = ((q/x2)+x2)/ 2

asi hasta x20 , como podeis ver para calcular la siguiente x usa el valor de la anterior , me esta costando bastante lo de la recursividad , hasta la fecha operaciones sencillas tipo calcular numeros fibonacci los he entendido bastante bien , pero en este ejercicio estoy totalmente bloqueado.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Según tu enunciado he intentado crear una implementación:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduce valor inicial q: ");
        int q = sc.nextInt();
        
        recursivo(q, 1);
    }
    
    public static double recursivo(double q, int x){
        if(x == 21){
            return q;
        } else {
            if(x != 1){
                q = ((q/(x-1))+(x-1))/2;
                System.out.println("x" + x + " = " + q);
            }
            x = x + 1;
            return recursivo(q, x);
        }
    }
}
```

En primer lugar, necesitamos un `Scanner` para leer el valor dado por teclado. Es entonces cuando se llama a la función `recursivo` con el valor `q` dado por teclado y el valor 1 porque se empieza con que `x1=1`.

Dentro de la función recursivo (que recibe por parámetros `q` de tipo `double` porque las operaciones darán números decimales, y `x` que es de tipo `int`) se tienen dos posibles casos, que x sea ya x20 en cuyo caso devuelve el valor de q. El otro caso, es el caso recursivo. Primero compruebo si x es igual o no a 1 porque en el paso inicial x1=1 y no necesita realizarse la operación. En cada llamada recursiva, se ejecuta `x = x + 1` para ir incrementando su valor. Dentro de la condición se puede ver la operación que has especificado de `((q/x)+x)/ 2`. Nótese que hago `x-1` porque por ejemplo para calcular x3 necesitamos x2. Una vez se ha calculado, imprimo en la consola el valor de x y de q en ese momento. Por último, para que la función sea realmente recursiva, se vuelve a llamar a sí misma con el valor calculado de q y la x que hemos incrementado en la línea anterior.

Espero que esto sea lo que tenías en mente y que te haya servido de ayuda.